# Не получается расположить блоки в ряд

Tags: html, css

Блоки начинают уезжать, не знаю, почему. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь на помощь )

Делаю здесь, при разрешении меньше 767, http://freeweblance.ru/

Comment: добавляй разметку и стили непосредственно в вопрос. По внешнему виду можно предположить, что картинки вложены друг в друга, а не все в одном контейнере

Comment: Я адрес сайта прикрепил, на котором делаю. Там можно посмотреть непосредственно.

Comment: И мы наверное должны обшарить весь сайт, что бы найти это самое место, так как горим огромным желанием тебе помочь?

Comment: @Александр, ссылки могут являться лишь дополнением к вопросу, все необходимое должно быть **непосредственно** внутри вопроса

Comment: Хорошо, так и буду делать, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

должно быть одно "row" а в row должны быть class="col..."

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
      <img ...>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
      <img ...>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
      <img ...>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-1"><img ...></div>
  <div class="col-lg-1"><img ...></div>
  <div class="col-lg-1"><img ...></div>
 </div>
</div>